# How to decode a binary data string in typescript

Tags: string, typescript, encryption, serialization, binary

I am working with a library that implemented the signal messanging protocol in typescript. Whenever I encrypt an message I receive  a `string` like te following one

[image]

This looks like a serialized object, for e.g opening an `.bin` file. My problem is that I can't use this string, because the characters in it are not valid. I have also tried to cast and convert this serialized data to an `ArrayBuffer` or `UInt8Array`, but without success.

How can I achieve to en- and decode this binary data to a normal string

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about typescript. If you know how it is done it javascript, you can do it in TypeScript as well. Here is a code snippet you can use in your code.

`function binaryToString(str) {
var binString = '';

str.split(' ').map(function(bin) {
    binString += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bin, 2));
});
return binString;

}
console.log(binaryToString('01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100'));`